# checking auto generated text field value by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am trying to apply some condition for an Auto generated textfield, the script objective is to edit-in-place user data by using Jquery, which is working fine, what i need here is to apply if the text field was empty , an alert message will popup

here is my Jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#inplace_field').blur(function(){
         if ($('#inplace_field').html(''))
         {
             alert ("its empty");
         }
        });
    });
```

the auto generated field will come if i click on a specific data that is called inside a `<p></p>` html paragraph.

when i click the paragraph will call automatically a text field that has the existed value inside it and it will be ready to change like this

```
<p id="userEmailAddress" class="givemeMarginHere editInPlace-active" style="background-color: transparent; ">
<form class="inplace_form" style="display: inline; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<input type="text" name="inplace_value" class="inplace_field" id="inplace_field" size="null">
<button class="inplace_save" value="">Save</button> 
<button class="inplace_cancel" value="">Cancel</button>
</form></p>
```

**The Problem**

my Jquery function doesn't show my alert even if let the textfield empty and moved to another object by clicking tab, it doesn't work.

-i want to mention that i called Jquery library and it works perfect with other Jquery scripts inside the page
- also `#inplace_field` is a unique `id` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, selector.html("any content") sets the html value of the selected object. What you want to do is retrieve the html value and compare it to blank.

```
     if ($('#inplace_field').html() == "")
     {
         alert ("its empty");
     }
```

I've also had good luck using .text() and .val(), depending on what effect you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

`html('')` will nulls innerHTML of your input field. To check if it's empty you need to check value using `val()` function. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#inplace_field').blur(function(){
         if ($('#inplace_field').val() == '') {
             alert ("its empty");
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried it on Fiddle and it worked , but not on my script , if you realize the html code , the value will come inside the button `save` not the auto generated field, which i do not know how or why ! and the wired thing , it works with my database !

Comment: Maybe because you setting value using `html()` function instead of `val()`?

Comment: i am afraid you did not understand me, please read my comment again

Comment: the value saved inside this `<button class="inplace_save" value="">Save</button>` not the textfield , there is not value inside the textfield when its created

Comment: Ok so in selector you can use `if ($('.inplace_save').val()...` instead